# Selenium IDE clicking checkbox doesn't work after downloading file

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

Using the Selenium IDE in Chrome I am making a test for a process on a website.

I have a website, where I need to click a checkbox to accept the terms of use, privacy terms etc. after the login. I can check those boxes without a problem through Selenium, but I can't check the box for the client terms. I have to download those first, what works without a problem. Selenium then doesn't check the accept box though.

I am using the whole xpath and when I tell Selenium to show me the element in the website, it shows me the correct one. I copied the xpath directly out of Chrome. I'm using following command.

```
Command: click
Target: xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/label
```

I also tried following other targets, none of them worked. Nevertheless Selenium always showed the right label when I clicked the option "Find Target in Page".

```
css=.terms-client label
xpath=//div[3]/div[3]/label
xpath=//label[contains(.,'Ich akzeptiere die Prüfungsbestimmungen')]
```

I tried check instead of click too, what didn't work. This is the HTML-code of the affected element, after the client terms have been downloaded already.

```
<div class="terms-client card" ng-repeat="role in data.roles" style="">
    <div class="header">Kandidat/-in: Elektroniker/in EFZ CH</div>
    <div class="content">
        <p ng-bind-html="(role.description || ('terms.client.terms'|trans))|nl2br">Bitte studieren Sie die Prüfungsbestimmungen sorgfältig.</p>
        <span iv-ipa-dokument="role.url" btn-class="btn-fill" download-state="role.downloaded" btn-label="Bestimmungen herunterladen"><button ng-click="download(url)" class="btn btn-fill" ng-disabled="disabled"><i class="icon icon-check-square-o" ng-class="class"></i> Bestimmungen herunterladen</button></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accept">
        <!---->
        <input id="client-accept-0" class="checkbox-new client-accept ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="checkbox" ng-model="role.state" ng-disabled="!data.agb || role.accepted || !role.downloaded">
        <label for="client-accept-0">Ich akzeptiere die Prüfungsbestimmungen</label>
        <!---->
    </div>
</div>
```

The label at the end is the part I would like to click. I don't understand why Selenium is able to check the other boxes and accept those terms, but not this one.

I noticed, the issue is, that the click stops working after downloading the terms. Before that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the locator being used to locate the checkbox. With the information provided, I guess the click event isn't handled for the label used.

Instead of getting the XPATH of the label, you need to select the input tag of the checkbox you need to click.

In this case the xpath of the element to select should be :

```
//label[contains(.,'Ich akzeptiere die Prüfungsbestimmungen')]/../input
```

Clicking using this element selector should perform the intended click.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer but that didn't solve the issue. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the exception that you are getting?

Comment: Thats part of the problem. I don't get an exception. Just nothing happens.

Comment: I just noticed, the box get clicked, if I don't download the terms first, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution but a workaround. A simple reload of the page after the download managed to solve my issue.